# Get HTML entities when using iTextsharp to export Gridview to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, itext

I faced a problem when I using `iTextSharp` to convert `Gridview` to `pdf`.

See this `gridview` on page, which works fine:

[image: image1]

but after converting to `pdf`, you can see `&` is converted to `&amp;` and blank to `&nbsp;`

[image: image2]

What should I do to make the `pdf` parse right text, but no `html` entities?

PS: The data contain chinese so I have to set chinese font to display the content.

PPS: The convert made my header of grid disappear, what's wrong with the code?

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceList"
                    AllowSorting="True" CssClass="table"
                    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#92D6C3">
                </asp:GridView>
```

cs:

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(stringWrite.ToString());
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
            //doc.SetMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);

            //設定中文
            BaseFont BaseF = BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\kaiu.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            Font fontCh = new Font(BaseF, 10);

            doc.Open();
            int gvRowsCount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            PdfPTable ptb = new PdfPTable(gvRowsCount);
            ptb.WidthPercentage = 98f;
            //表格標題
            for (int h = 0; h < gvRowsCount; h++)
            {
                ptb.AddCell(new Phrase(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[h].Text, fontCh));
            }
            ptb.HeaderRows = 1;

            //表格內文
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < gvRowsCount; j++)
                {
                    ptb.AddCell(new Phrase(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text, fontCh));

                }
            }
            //寫入並關閉
            doc.Add(ptb);
            doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using iText 5 instead of iText 7? https://nuget.org/packages/itext7 If you have a support contract for iText 5, please contact support at iText Software. If you don't have a support contract, please upgrade to iText 7.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie There are no many articles with iText 7,but I'll give a try. Thank you!